# Metadata Navigation not working elsewhere than site settings

Tags: 2013, custom-masterpage, managed-navigation, settings, site-settings

I'm coming to a really strange behavior of SharePoint 2013 Metadata Navigation.
I have set a list of terms for the top navigation, at the "root" of my site (aka the highest level of SharePoint, http://mysitecollection)

So, i wanted this top navigation to display my levels like:

```
- level1 A
- level1 B
   |- Level2 B.1
   |- Level2 B.2
- level1 C
   |- Level2 C.1
      |- Level3 C.1.1
```

And getting those little submenus.

But this does only work when I'm on a site or library/list settings!
I don't see it display on home, for example. On home, I only see level 1. But absolutely no level 1's children...

**Do you have any idea on what is happening?**

**Do you have any idea on how to fix it?**

Answer (score 1):

Finally got it, SharePoint has a really strange behavior.
What i did not tell in my question was that I was using a custom Master Page.

And it seemed to be the problem : I have generated the snippet for the DeltaTopNavigation through the Snippet Gallery. And apparently SharePoint has a bug with this.

So, the solution is : **go to seattle.master, select the DeltaTopNavigation snippet and paste it to your custom master page**.

I let the code here, if anyone wants to see it.

```
<SharePoint:AjaxDelta id="DeltaTopNavigation" BlockElement="true" CssClass="ms-displayInline" runat="server">
     <SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" ControlId="TopNavigationDataSource" Id="topNavigationDelegate">
      <Template_Controls>
        <asp:SiteMapDataSource ShowStartingNode="False" SiteMapProvider="SPNavigationProvider" id="topSiteMap" runat="server" StartingNodeUrl="sid:1002" />
      </Template_Controls>
     </SharePoint:DelegateControl>
     <a name="startNavigation">
     </a>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderTopNavBar" runat="server">
        <SharePoint:AspMenu ID="TopNavigationMenu" Runat="server" EnableViewState="false" DataSourceID="topSiteMap" AccessKey="&lt;%$Resources:wss,navigation_accesskey%&gt;" UseSimpleRendering="true" UseSeparateCss="false" Orientation="Horizontal" StaticDisplayLevels="2" AdjustForShowStartingNode="true" MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="2" SkipLinkText="" />

    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
 </SharePoint:AjaxDelta>
```

**Source that helped me :**

[Sharepoint 2013 Managed Navigation Lessons Learned by Kyle Wright](http://blogs.c5insight.com/Home/tabid/40/entryid/378/SharePoint-2013-Managed-Navigation-Lessons-Learned.aspx) (see the paragraph "Using Managed Navigation in a Custom Master Page")